# Notepad++ Large dataset multiple edition

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to remember a specific combination of keys in Notepad++ that enables to select and edit multiples rows at the same time, doing my first selection and repeating the same below.

I have multiple rows with the following structure and I want to select from the first number to the comma, only to keep just the second number for each row on the text file.

```
20220731040242,1268568
20220731040241,58081
20220731040237,140770
```

I know that the combination <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN_ARROW</kbd> enables me to do so or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>left-click</kbd>, but it is a large dataset (10,000+ rows), so is not efficient.

I know there is a way because I've used it before, but I forgot the key combination.

Comment: The page-up and page-down keys can be used as well and the four arrow keys..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find & Replace with regex:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*,`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Toto, I ended up using ALT + SHIFT + avpag to travel faster and edit each row on same column index

Comment: @FelipeRojas: OK, that's right but be aware that works only when each columns have same length.